# Is it mention anywhere in the Midrash or other Rabbinic literature that when moshiach comes people will no longer be able to have children

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, mitzvah, messiah, children

Is it mention anywhere in the Midrash or the Mishna or the Talmud or the Gemara or other Rabbinic literature that when moshiach comes people will no longer be able to have children?

Comment: Is there any reason you think it might be? For example, did someone tell you this?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure that's entirely accurate, what you probably heard is something based on this quote in the Talmud, [Yevamot 62a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62a.17?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en):

> רב הונא אמר קיים משום דרב אסי דאמר רב אסי אין בן דוד בא עד שיכלו כל נשמות שבגוף שנאמר (ישעיהו נז, טז) כי רוח מלפני יעטוף וגו' ורבי יוחנן אמר לא קיים פריה ורביה לשבת יצרה בעינן והא ליכא The Gemara clarifies the reasons for their opinions: Rav Huna said he has fulfilled the mitzva due to a statement of Rav Asi, as Rav Asi said that the reason for this mitzva is that **the Messiah, son of David, will not come until all the souls of the body have been finished**, i.e., until all souls that are destined to inhabit physical bodies will do so.

Which seems to mean that one necessary (though not necessarily sufficient) criterion for moshiach to come is that a certain number of humans have been born. That's not exactly your quote, but I see how someone could have creatively read it that way.

Comment: You are correct that his is the basis for what Mark Shanosky is asking. This concept is discussed in depth in the name of the Ari z"l in Sha'ar HaGilgulim & Sefer HaGilgulim in the opening chapters. The essence  of the idea is that except for a few exceptions, all souls are fragments/fractals of the inclusive soul of Adam HaRishon. All of our avodah is to correct the blemish that introduced by him. When the job of all those souls is complete, there will be no need for further reincarnation.

Comment: Comment con't. There is a 2nd category of souls also discussed that do not originate from that inclusive soul of Adam HaRishon. They are not associated with that blemish and are not a part of the  group mentioned by Rav Huna. According to Chassidic tradition, the Ba'al Shem Tov and the Ba'al HaTanya were two examples of this second category.